# Automatic check-out on VS2010, TFS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am using VS 2010 and TFS 2010. By default or without configuring options on VS, are files checked out automatically when the attribute is set from read-only to normal? So PendEdit(Filename) is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

if you manually change the read only attribute on the file then no. If you edit the read only file in VS it'll check out the file automatically for you